# How to simplify fraction with fractional exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to simplify 
$\left(\dfrac {3x^{\frac 3 2} y^3} {x^2 y^{-\frac 1 2}}\right)^{-2}$? 
I am able to simplify the fractional exponents into radicals, but I am having trouble getting to the solution of $\dfrac x {9y^7}$.

Comment: I get $ 3 y^{\frac{7}{2}} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} $.  Where are you getting $ \dfrac{x}{9y^7} $ ?

Comment: there was a crucial typo, it supposed to be all in parenthisis then squared!

Comment: There is a trick to putting parentheses around a complex object like that in MathJax. I did that for you and squared it. I hope now it is what you wanted.

Comment: Somehow though this still comes out to $\frac{9y^7}{x}$. Maybe it was supposed to be a power of $-2$ instead of just squaring it?

Comment: yes, -2 . You are right.

Comment: By the way, this is a very minor thing, but the style guide for this site says $x^{3/2}$ is preferred over the format $x^{\frac32}$. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5057. You can fix this too if you like, or just keep it in mind for the next time. (It will actually save some keystrokes for you next time.)

Comment: If you have received answers but decide to change the question, it is polite to signal this to the persons who have already answered, or else their answers will look unrelated to the new version of your question (and they might get downvotes).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you have to subtract powers of the same variable. Therefore your expresion is

$$\left( 3 x^{\frac 3 2 - 2} y^{3 - (- \frac 1 2)} \right) ^{-2}= \left( 3 x^{- \frac 1 2} y^{\frac 7 2} \right) ^{-2} = \frac x {9 y^7} .$$

There are no steps other than the ones explicitly layed out above.

Comment: The question isn't about the best result, but about the way.

Comment: @danielAzuelos: Which I have answered in the clear and simple sentence "you have to subtract powers of the same variable", showing next explicitly how to do this. Not to mention that there is a *single* result, not a "best" one.

Comment: The question was changed after you answered it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

1. bring everything to the numerator,
2. group constants, group variables

Answer (score 0):

Same exact question found on related search, could not have answered better

[Simplify with fractional exponents and negative exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394954/simplify-with-fractional-exponents-and-negative-exponents?rq=1)